# How to retrieve spanid using java in Sleuth version 2.0.4

Tags: spring-boot, trace, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I need to know the SpandId in java code but I don't know how to get it. I had been searching and I found that many people refer to Tracer class, but it is not available at sleuth 2.0.4.

Does anybody know how to get the SpandId using sleuth 2.0.4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inject the `brave.Tracer` bean and then you can call `tracer.currentSpan().context().spanId()` or `tracer.currentSpan().context().spanIdString()`